# Django debug 404 error

Tags: django

**UPDATE**
The error log in the email has

```
Internal Server Error: /lifestyle/the-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve404()
  File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, in resolve404
    return self._resolve_special('404')
  File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 386, in _resolve_special
    return get_callable(callback), {}
  File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 118, in get_callable
    (lookup_view, mod_name))
ViewDoesNotExist: Could not import common.views.search_404_view. View does not exist in module common.views.
```

common.views:

```
import datetime, calendar, re

from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.redirects.models import Redirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import Http404,  HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from common.models import Area, Category, HotItem
from stats.models import FileNotFoundItem
from stats.models import StatItem

from articles.models import Article
from events.models import Event
from marketplace.models import Entry
from directory.models import Venue



class StatsDetailView(DetailView):
    message = ""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        if not self.object.visible and self.object.created_by != self.request.user:
            raise Http404


        today = datetime.date.today()
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.object)
        try:
            si = StatItem.objects.get(
                date=today,
                content_type=ct,
                object_id=self.object.id,
            )
            si.hits = si.hits +1
            si.save()
        except StatItem.DoesNotExist:
            StatItem.objects.create(
                date=today,
                content_type=ct,
                object_id=self.object.id,
            )
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

class AreaList(ListView):
    model = Area
    context_object_name = 'areas'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Area.objects.filter(parent=None).exclude(slug='not-found')

class AreaDetail(StatsDetailView):
    model = Area
    context_object_name = 'area'
    context_object = None

    def get_object(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('slug', None):
            slugs = self.kwargs['slug'].strip('/').split('/')
            self.context_object = get_object_or_404(Area, slug=slugs[-1])
            return self.context_object
        raise Http404

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        context = super(AreaDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        area_ids = [a.id for a in self.context_object.get_child_areas()]
        area_ids.append(self.context_object.id)
        context['events'] = Event.objects.filter(venue__area__in=area_ids, visible=True).order_by('hot', '-created')[:10]
        context['entries'] = Entry.objects.filter(area__in=area_ids, visible=True).order_by('hot', '-created')[:10]
        context['venues'] = Venue.objects.filter(area__in=area_ids, visible=True).order_by('hot', '-created')[:10]
        context['areas'] = Area.objects.filter(parent=None, visible=True)
        return context

class CategoryList(ListView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'categories'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.filter(parent=None).exclude(slug='not-found')

class CategoryDetail(StatsDetailView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'category'
    context_object = None

    def get_object(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('slug', None):
            slugs = self.kwargs['slug'].strip('/').split('/')
            self.context_object = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slugs[-1])
            return self.context_object
        raise Http404

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        context = super(CategoryDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        category_ids = [c.id for c in self.context_object.get_child_categories()]
        category_ids.append(self.context_object.id)
        context['events'] = Event.objects.filter(categories__in=category_ids, visible=True).order_by('hot', '-created')[:10]
        context['entries'] = Entry.objects.filter(category__in=category_ids, visible=True).order_by('hot', '-created')[:10]
        context['venues'] = Venue.objects.filter(categories__in=category_ids, visible=True).order_by('hot', '-created')[:10]
        context['articles'] = Article.objects.filter(categories__in=category_ids, visible=True).order_by('hot', '-created')[:10]
        return context
```

I haven't found the view but I want to rewrite the view. Looking for an example view for the 404 page.

I'm debugging an issue on a site I'm maintaining so most of the code wasn't written by me. On a link like www.example.com/lifestyle/the- when debug is False throws an Internal Server Error but when I set debug to True I get Page Not Found error. This is the error

`VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [top_menu] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {}]"`,

top_menu is the top menu on the site. It loads okay on the site however.
The view that calls get object or 404 is

`context['page'] = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=slugs[0], parent=None)`

and the 404 template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Page Not Found {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="stack">
    <h1 class="stackContent">Page <span>Not</span> Found</span></h1>
    <div class="box stackContent">
        We are sorry but we can't find the page you tried to access.
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I know for 404 pages it used to return a list of suggestion pages so I believe it was using haystack to do this. So my guess is there's a view that overrides the 404 call, I'm looking for how this is done.

Comment: If it's 500 when `DEBUG=False` you should receive the email with the detailed error included and line where the exception occurred. If you don't, add yourself to the ADMINS in the settings.py and restart the service.I'm pretty sure the error is in some other place (404 should't return this kind of error at least there is some custom exception handler). Look where in the code you try to access the `top_menu` from the dictionary etc.

Comment: Thanks I'm checking that now.

Answer (score 1):

I created this view in common.views and it fixed the issue

```
def search_404_view(request, template_name='404.html'):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```